# What was the first supersonic wind tunnel?

Tags: aviation-history, wind-tunnel

What was the world's first supersonic wind tunnel? Who built it and how did it work?

All I've found so far is this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_tunnel#World_War_Two) article that says:

> By the end of the war, Germany had at least three different supersonic wind tunnels, with one capable of Mach 4.4 (heated) airflows.

The citation in the article is a dead link.

Comment: The German tunnels were in Aachen (1936, 0.1x0.1 m), Göttingen (1938, 0.11x0.13m) and  Peenemünde (1939, 0.4x0.4m, Mach 4.4).

Comment: @mns Thanks but do you have a source so I can look them up?

Comment: I knew about the locations from different sources (Bölkow's "Erinnerungen", some googling...). For the years and cross-sections I looked in the same book as aeroalias answer. However, I'm surprised that the tunnel in Göttingen was built so late: reading the phrase before aeroalias citation ("The first suggestion to build a supersonic wind tunnel according to the vacuum-storage principle was made by Ludwig Prandtl in 1917. [...] however, the tunnel could not be realized until the end of World War One. During the same year...") I'd have though that it was built in the early 20s too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The world's first supersonic wind tunnel started operating in National Physical Laboratory in Teddington, England in 1922.

It basically used a pressure tank upstream, which was used to generate supersonic flow in a cross section of 20.3 mm, which was used to study projectiles.

From the book [Aeronautical Research in Germany: From Lilienthal until Today](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eJ7oCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=first+supersonic+wind+tunnel&source=bl&ots=YAsWPljZxc&sig=xdf4Y9PkgwxcuAin94Nw4lGAxWU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGrvTQ-ujQAhUFLo8KHT9cC8wQ6AEILTAK#v=onepage&q=first%20supersonic%20wind%20tunnel&f=false):

> During the same year, the National Physical Laboratory (NPL) in Teddington/England started operating, for the first time ever, a supersonic wind tunnel based on the pressure storage principle ...